# How to add second image in PDF?

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter, html2canvas, pdfmake

I'm new here.
I mainly deal with backend programming (OOP PHP) but I also have to do some frontend stuff.
I'm currently working on creating a PDF (client side) with html2canvas and pdfmake.
In this PDF I have to include 2 dynamically loaded graphics (canvas js), table and map (leaflat js).
So far everything went well (I did everything else) but I do not know how to add the second graphic to my PDF.

CODE:

```
html2canvas($("#chartdiv"), {
   onrendered: function(canvas) {
   var myImage = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
   //here i can add table, map and variable myImage to my docdefinition content and call pdfMake.createPdf(docDefinition).download(); to download the pdf.
   }
});
//i want to use variable myImage here.
```

This work fine, but how i can use variable myImage outside the function to add in my docdefinition content to create my pdf with pdfmake?
I'm trying to define global variable but not work.
I do not use jspDF because I can not use Cyrillic there and my PDF contains Cyrillic.

Thanks a lot for the help!

Answer (score 0):

you assigned the var inside the function,better You’ll have to assign it  that can  accessible from the outside.

```
var myImage;

html2canvas($("#chartdiv"), {
   onrendered: function(canvas) {
   myImage = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
   //here i can add table, map and variable myImage to my docdefinition content and call pdfMake.createPdf(docDefinition).download(); to download the pdf.
   }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but i try this and don't work. When i assigned the var otside the function like this "var myImage = null" and then i add alert(myImage) after function the result is null.